# how to do offline detection instead on real time?

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I have implemented contour detection code using opencv 2.3 in real time. I have use my web camera for it.
Now  I want to implement it in captured video which are recorded previously and are in my database.

```
cv::Mat frame;
cv::Mat back;
cv::Mat fore;
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;
bg.nmixtures = 3;
bg.bShadowDetection = true;

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
```

I have not mention my whole code because to load an AVI file I have to do formation here only.

Please anyone can guide me?

Thanx.

Comment: I am not sure, where the problem is? Do you need help extracting frames from an AVI?

Comment: hi I need help extracting frames from AVI files which is stored in my laptop. I further want to ask that the length of the AVI file should b less or it is for any length. thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a video and read a frame with the following code snippet:

```
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture cap("/path/to/file.avi");
bool ok = cap.open();
// check for errors
cap >> frame; // or cap.read(frame);
```

You can read about the documentation for [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) for more details. If you encounter problems, you should check, [if your video's codec is supported](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs).

Comment: hi.sry for the gap.I tried using ur suggestion but I am not getting the result. build errors are there.can you help me editing in my code?please.

Comment: I can try, but I do not have visual-c++ experience.